# how to validate id and ensure that is found in another table before inserting data using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have three tables
first  table for articles

| id | content |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | dummy content_1 |
| 2 | dummy content_2 |
| 3 | dummy content_3 |
| 4 | dummy content_4 |
| 5 | dummy content_5 |

and another for categories

| id | category_name | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | movies | movies |
| 2 | men health | men-health |
| 3 | tech | tech |
| 4 | games | games |
| 5 | food | food |

and third table for defining categories for  each article

| article_id | category_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 |

and i am using normal insert statement to  insert data into third table
and while inserting the IDs into the third table i want to validate if they found in first and second table i.e if i am inserting the following row

| article_id | category_id |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |

i want to check if there is article id 3 and there is category id 1
in one query and if one of them not found cancel the insertion process
how i write a query for this ?

Comment: What is the point of the column `category_id` in the table `articles` if you define categories for each article in the 3d table?

Comment: sorry for  this mistake, I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

first of all make the `id` column primary key on each tables `categories` and `articles`

```
ALTER TABLE categories
ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);

ALTER TABLE articles
ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

just add a foreign key constraint for the two columns

```
ALTER TABLE article_category
ADD FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories(id);

ALTER TABLE article_category
ADD FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES articles(id);
```

Comment: I think your misunderstood my question , what I  want is while inserting new row in the third table i want to ensure that  inserted category_id  is existing in categories table and article_id is existing in articles table

Comment: Ok, I understand you now, I will edit my answer check it

Comment: yes it worked, thanks dear